# Set Up Table Fixed Element with 2 Head

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I try to set up a responsive table with 2 fixed header in left, so the body is scrollable but the left header is fixed.

I expect the result is like this

[image]

My code:

I add position sticky and z index to each head but the second head from left is override the first head.

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0; overflow: auto;">
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <col />
        <col />
        <colgroup span="3"></colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th colspan="31" scope="colgroup" style="text-align: center;">JANUARI</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="width: 10%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="8" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;" scope="rowgroup">Assy To GFG</th>
                <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Plan</th>
                // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Act</th>
             // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">F/G</th>
                // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Kum P</th>
                // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Kum A</th>
               // data 
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Kum F/G</th>
                // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Blc P</th>
                 // data
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row" style="position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1;">Blc D</th>
                // data
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But the result is like this
[image]

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your question where the error is reproducable?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `JQuery DataTable` (as you tagged the question with jquery I will assume you could accept this kind of answer)

Simply add the jquery datatable plugin and the following script. It will be better if you write an `Id` for the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('.table ').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            left: 1
        }
    } );
} );
```

Functional example and library:
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

When you download or select a CDN, don't forget check the option "Fixed Columns"
or you can use the following:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the plugin is larger than jquery itself...

Comment: @imhvost  of course, is the better plugin to present datatables, used in every site, responsive, even more this plugin add a lot of functionalities and is suggested to replace any table with large amount of data. If you are corcen by the size, is not even bigger than any other element and CDN will cache the element. Also, has a very large support since 15 years

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use scripts here.
You can do without plugins. The bottom line is that you need to set the same height for the rows of the tables. Something like this :

```js
setSizeTables();
$(window).on('resize', setSizeTables);

function setSizeTables(){
  $('.scroll-x-table').each(function(){
    const table = $(this);
    const wrapp = table.closest('.scroll-x-table-wrapp');
    const ths = wrapp.find('.scroll-x-ths');
    wrapp.find('tr').css('height', 0);
    ths.find('tr').each(function(index){
      const tr = $(this);
      const tableTr = table.find('tr').eq(index);
      const trHeight = Math.ceil( tr.height() );
      const tableTrHeight = Math.ceil( tableTr.height() );
      const largeHeight = trHeight > tableTrHeight ? trHeight : tableTrHeight;
      tr.height(largeHeight);
      tableTr.height(largeHeight);
    })
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scroll-x-table-wrapp {
  --width: 600px;
  --ths-width: 100px;
  --border-color: #ccc;
  --bg-color: #f0f0f0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: var(--width);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.scroll-x-ths {
  flex: none;
  width: var(--ths-width);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.scroll-x-ths td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  border: solid 1px var(--border-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
.scroll-x-table-body {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-right: solid 1px var(--border-color);
}
.scroll-x-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.scroll-x-table thead {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
.scroll-x-table td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid 1px var(--border-color);
  min-width: 200px; /* optional */
}
.scroll-x-table td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
.scroll-x-table td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-x-table-wrapp">
  <table class="scroll-x-ths">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="scroll-x-table-body">
    <table class="scroll-x-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>da<br>ta</td>
          <td>da<br>ta</td>
          <td>da<br>ta</td>
          <td>da<br>ta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tableFixHeader {
  overflow: auto;
  width:100%;
}

.tableFixHeader table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.tableFixHeader tr th, .tableFixHead tr td {
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
.tableFixHeader tr td{
padding: 7px 14px;
  border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.tableFixHeader tr td:first-child, .tableFixHeader tr th:first-child {
  position:sticky;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:#efefef;
  border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
.tableFixHeader tr td:nth-child(1),.tableFixHeader tr th:nth-child(1)  { 
position:sticky;
  left:0px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color: #efefef;
   border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
   border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
  }
.tableFixHeader th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #efefef;
  z-index:2
}
.tableFixHeader tr th:first-child , .tableFixHeader tr th:nth-child(1) {
  z-index:3
  }
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHeader">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a#</th>
        <th>01</th>
        <th>02</th>
        <th>03</th>
        <th>04</th>
        <th>05</th>
        <th>06</th>
        <th>07</th>
        <th>08</th>
        <th>09</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a4</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a5</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a6</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a7</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a8</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
        <td>0.34257454</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your first cell sticky by default using regular CSS-

```
.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

2. Make second cell also sticky but **second cell's position from left should be equal to first cell's width so it would not override the first cell when scrolling.** And you need to do this using jquery.

Here is a working demo-

```js
let first_cell_width = $('table td:nth-child(1)').innerWidth() + 'px';
$('table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2)').css('left', first_cell_width);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #fff222;
}

.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sticky-column">Sticky Column 1</th>
      <th class="sticky-column">Sticky Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
      <th>Column 11</th>
      <th>Column 12</th>
      <th>Column 13</th>
      <th>Column 14</th>
      <th>Column 15</th>
      <th>Column 16</th>
      <th>Column 17</th>
      <th>Column 18</th>
      <th>Column 19</th>
      <th>Column 20</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">Sticky Cell 1</td>
      <td class="sticky-column">Sticky Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
      <td>Cell 9</td>
      <td>Cell 10</td>
      <td>Cell 11</td>
      <td>Cell 12</td>
      <td>Cell 13</td>
      <td>Cell 14</td>
      <td>Cell 15</td>
      <td>Cell 16</td>
      <td>Cell 17</td>
      <td>Cell 18</td>
      <td>Cell 19</td>
      <td>Cell 20</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more rows... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```